# RHEL 8. can't install packages due to not reciving updates

Tags: linux, rhel

Whatever package i want to instal, such error msg pops up

> This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
>   Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".

Recommended solution posted on redhat web page 'subscription manager attach --auto' doesnt work. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Either pay for the registration, get a registration for free/reduced price (perhaps educational use or some such?), or migrate to [CentOS](https://www.centos.org). That one is build from the very same sources as RHEL, and should even be bug-for-bug compatible. It is just a community effort, with *absolutely* no guarantee of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered with the same issue and I found the below steps on a site which i have tried and It has fixed them

Below are the steps.

```
# subscription-manager attach --auto
```

Once done, review the status using the command " # subscription-manager status" and it should be "current". If still not working then do a complete clean up of subscriptions from your system and re-register it. Run the below commands in the same order:

```
# subscription-manager remove --all
# subscription-manager unregister
# subscription-manager clean
# yum clean all
# rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
# subscription-manager register
# subscription-manager attach --auto
```

Once this is done, verify the subscription status and checkout the populate the repository:

```
# subscription-manager status
# yum repolist
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped me on Virtualbox VM, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa):

Error:
When performing yum command:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.

This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.

Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".
```

The solution for me was to remove and add subscriptions again RHEL8:

```
#subscription-manager remove --all        
#subscription-manager clean
#subscription-manager register --username <redhatusernamehere> --auto-attach
#dnf repolist or yum repolist
```

(Result should be:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
repo id                                  repo name
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)     
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
```

`#yum check-update or dnf check-update` (Check if updates are available)